# How can I remove the domain name from the domainname command?

Tags: 20.04

How can I remove the domain name from the `domainname` command on ubuntu? I am unable to find anything related to this. I set my domain name using `domainname example.com`

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you set it with domainname command - it'll be reverted when you reboot

otherwise you may need to edit the /etc/hostname file